# How can I avoid "for" loops with an "if" condition inside them with C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

With almost all code I write, I am often dealing with set reduction problems on collections that ultimately end up with naive "if" conditions inside of them. Here's a simple example:

```
for(int i=0; i<myCollection.size(); i++)
{
     if (myCollection[i] == SOMETHING)
     {
           DoStuff();
     }
}
```

With functional languages, I can solve the problem by reducing the collection to another collection (easily) and then perform all operations on my reduced set. In pseudocode:

```
newCollection <- myCollection where <x=true
map DoStuff newCollection
```

And in other C variants, like C#, I could reduce with a where clause like

```
foreach (var x in myCollection.Where(c=> c == SOMETHING)) 
{
   DoStuff();
}
```

Or better (at least to my eyes)

```
myCollection.Where(c=>c == Something).ToList().ForEach(d=> DoStuff(d));
```

Admittedly, I am doing a lot of paradigm mixing and subjective/opinion based style, but I can't help but feel that I am missing something really fundamental that could allow me to use this preferred technique with C++. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Out of C++ standard library functionality, you can try `std::copy_if`, but the selections aren't lazy

Comment: if it is ok for you to make a copy, you might want to take a look at [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: You may be interested in [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).  It should also be coming to C++ as a TS and hopefully standardized in a future release.

Comment: `c++11` has lambda expressions, so that may be something you would want to look at as well.

Comment: I suggest that you change the title because both answers uses the loops

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are interested by the performance aspects, or solely by the syntactic aspects?

Comment: As far as I know that C# piece of code won't compile. `:` has to be replaced by `in`

Comment: To add to @NullException's comment, the other C# snippet also won't compile because there is [intentionally](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) no `ForEach` in `IEnumerable`

Comment: I feel the need to point out that the `if` inside a `for` you mention is not only pretty much functionally equivalent to the other examples but would also probably be faster in a lot of cases. Also for someone who claims to like functional style, what you're promoting seems to go against functional programming's dearly beloved concept of purity since `DoStuff` clearly has side effcets.

Comment: If you're doing this *many many times* with the same filter conditions I'd suggest using something like Boost multi_index which can maintain many indexes to the same data. It's like having your own DB in the app.

Comment: If you can, I guess you could sort your data to replace the for + if with just one for loop that iterates over the individuals that respect your conditions (or two loops in case of an else, and so on)

Comment: I've never really understood why people think combining all the logic onto *a single line* makes it look somehow better or more readable. Your C++ snippet at the very top is *by far* the most readable to me out of all of your possibilities. And since efficiency won't be changed, I cannot understand why you would prefer not to write that, unless you are being paid by number of lines of code that you delete.

Comment: @CodyGray  I second that.  I think the for loop with internal if is by far the most readable.  I'm not sure about the efficiency, except that it's probably really close.  Getting a subset and then iterating on the subset logically requires two traversals instead of one, and it still does the test for every element, so I prefer to traverse it once and explicitly show the test that's going to happen anyway for every element.  It's (barely) more efficient that way, and a lot more transparent.

Comment: @CodyGray Agreed: it' just syntactic sugar. And the question title is misleading, because it is very different _avoiding_ branching and _hiding_ it under abstraction.

Comment: @CodyGray: Today, efficiency is not changed. Tomorrow - might be. If you request filtering first, then a range for on that, then - I'm speculating here - filtering *might* execute in parallel (depending on your library) and *might* be faster (depending on your architecture). We don't know - but we don't want to rule it out.

Comment: @CodyGray One advantage in using things like `map`/`filter` to iterate over collections is that you *know* what they are going to do. A generic loop can do all kind of complex stuff and it's far easier to introduce a bug manually writing the `for` loop than writing `map doStuff collection`. This can also help the compiler when optimizing. The same is (more) true when writing a recursive function by hand or using something like  a `fold`/`reduce` instead.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody pointed out that boost does this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2274ee265d19a1a

Comment: If the compiler gets sufficiently smart that it is doing the kinds of amazing optimizations that you are imagining, @lorro, it should certainly be smart enough to detect common patterns and transform them so that it can perform the same optimizations. Which will make it important to write code in the normal, obvious way. Assuming of course that *any* of these optimizations are even possible, since they very likely break ordering guarantees provided by the language specification.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm not talking about your compiler, I'm talking about the library providing `filter()`. We're on agreement that it's non-trivial for a compiler (and it's non-trivial whether that should be done in the first place), however, with `std::async()` it's now almost trivial to write a `filter()` that does the filtering in the background (clearly stating this in the docs). As long as both your filter and loop body are sufficiently long and can run in parallel, this might speed up your code quite a bit.

Comment: @CodyGray: it's not necessarily about lines of code, it's also whether you prefer to deal in operations on a range, or prefer to loop over a range explicitly performing the equivalent operation on each element. Even without the conditional, and even before range-based for loops, some people still wouldn't use `std::for_each` if you had a gun to their head, on the basis that the loop is more readable to them in all cases. Whereas other people liked `for_each` so much they standardized it ;-)

Comment: As the OP says, the desire to remove the explicit `if` follows from a functional  style, c.f. http://degoes.net/articles/destroy-all-ifs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine a function and a predicate in for\_each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185132/how-to-combine-a-function-and-a-predicate-in-for-each)

Comment: @CodyGray it's because your're not expressing yourself at the correct abstraction level. https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/02/07/why-you-should-use-stdfor_each-over-range-based-for-loops/

Comment: @JonathanWakely yes the anti-if movement is sarcastic but it has a strong base of truth. And the actual metric is called `cyclomatic complexity`. Programming in functional ways allows you to perform code proofing... at all. the full Turing way of programming advocated by CodyGray bumps into the limits of decidability very fast.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

IMHO it's more straight forward and more readable to use a for loop with an if inside it. However, if this is annoying for you, you could use a `for_each_if` like the one below:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Pred, typename Op> 
void for_each_if(Iter first, Iter last, Pred p, Op op) {
  while(first != last) {
    if (p(*first)) op(*first);
    ++first;
  }
}
```

*Usecase:*

```
std::vector<int> v {10, 2, 10, 3};
for_each_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i){ return i > 5; }, [](int &i){ ++i; });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f418d1c5e0d82f0)

Comment: That is *exceptionally* clever. I will also agree that it isn't straight forward and I'll probably just use if conditions when programming C++ that is consumed by others. But that is exactly what I need for my own personal use! :)

Comment: would it be possible to instead just pass in `v` and use `std::begin` and `std::end` in the `for_each_if` function?

Comment: @Default Passing iterator pairs rather than containers is both more flexible and idiomatic C++.

Comment: @Default: or even better, take a `range` of templated type that's required to have `begin()` and `end()` (either own or external) and provide a `range(Iter first, Iter second)` for compatibility with iterators.

Comment: @MarkB: it was, before ranges and spans. Now the latter are a little safer because boundary checks are possible (i.e., you have less chance to mix up `end()`'s of two vectors).

Comment: `would it be possible to instead just pass in v and use std::begin and std::end in the for_each_if function?`: Sorry I misinterpreted the question. No that's not possible and as others suggested it wouldn't be flexible.

Comment: C++ is definitely missing ranges - you have to create new template function for every sneeze instead of grouping existing ones like it is done in functional languages. And the fact that we already have way too many algos that duplicate functionality proofs that.

Comment: @Slava, in general ranges won't reduce the number of algorithms. For example, you still need `find_if` and `find` whether they work on ranges or pairs of iterators. (There are a few exceptions, such as `for_each` and `for_each_n`). The way to avoid writing new algos for every sneeze is to use different operations with the existing algos, e.g instead of `for_each_if` embed the condition into the callable passed to `for_each`, e.g. `for_each(first, last, [&](auto& x) { if (cond(x)) f(x); });`

Comment: @JonathanWakely maybe we mean different when we say ranges, but what I mean is when you can combine algos into chain. Then you do not need `find_if` you just use `find` and chain it with `filter`, same for all other `_if` variants

Comment: @Slava, you don't want chaining for that, you want a `filter` that produces a view (i.e. lazily evaluates some other range), and just take the first element. But this is going off-topic for this answer

Comment: I'm gonna have to agree with the first sentence: The standard for-if solution is *much* more readable and easier to work with. I think the lambda syntax and the use of a template defined somewhere else just to handle a simple loop would irritate or possibly confuse other devs. You're sacrificing locality and performance for... what? Being able to write something in one line?

Comment: *Cough* @Darkenor, generally "*exceptionally* clever" programming [is to be avoided](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/25276/45992) because it annoys the crap out of everyone else including your future self.

Comment: This is a fine answer, but I don't see what's *exceptionally* clever about it.  It's a function that has a similar interface to functions in the standard library (e.g. `std::copy_if`, `std::for_each`), and the implementation is straightforward.

Comment: Downvoted: this is not in the spirit of what the OP asked. A filtered range (Boost, range-v3) is more idiomatic, easier to extend, and also reduces a potential M*N proliferation of algorithms and range modifiers (filter, reverse, zip etc) to a more manageable M+N vocabulary.

Comment: Agree with @ryan here. The OP code is significantly easier to understand and maintain than the clever code proposed here. I think the OP's main issue is he wants to use the functional paradigm in a language that is *not* made with it in mind... if OP wants to do functional programming, then a functional language should be used. Otherwise, he needs to think differently about the problem (e.g. in procedural or OO terms).

Comment: You could use variadic templates to extend this function to take any number of arguments and any function prototype. It's probably better to keep it this way, though.

Comment: How does this avoid the branch? There's still an if in there.

Answer (score 49):

Boost provides ranges that can be used w/ range-based for. Ranges have the advantage that they don't copy the underlying data structure, they merely provide a 'view' (that is, `begin()`, `end()` for the range and `operator++()`, `operator==()` for the iterator). This might be of your interest: http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct is_even
{
    bool operator()( int x ) const { return x % 2 == 0; }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    std::vector<int> myCollection{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for( int i: myCollection | filtered( is_even() ) )
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest to use the OPs example instead, i.e. `is_even` => `condition`, `input`=> `myCollection` etc.

Comment: This is a pretty excellent answer and definitely what I'm looking to do. I'm going to hold off on accepting unless someone can come up with a standard compliant way to do it that uses lazy/deferred execution. Upvoted.

Comment: @Darkenor: If Boost is a problem for you (for ex., you're banned to use it due to company policy & manager wisdom), I can come up with a simplified definition of `filtered()` for you - that said, it's better to use a supported lib than some ad-hoc code.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I accepted it because the standard-compliant way that came first because the question was geared to C++ itself, not the boost library. But this is really excellent. Also - yes, I have sadly worked in many-a-place that banned Boost for absurd reasons...

Comment: @LeeClagett: ?          .

Comment: @lorro I didn't see the delete button for comments

Comment: A note to this: if you use `boost::adaptors`, be sure to own the range (i.e., don't pass a temporary). This is especially tricky when you want multiple adaptors. This doesn't mean that `boost::adaptors` is wrong, it's just that you must be careful. See this bug for details: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7630

Answer (score 46):

Instead of creating a new algorithm, as the accepted answer does, you can use an existing one with a function that applies the condition:

```
std::for_each(first, last, [](auto&& x){ if (cond(x)) { ... } });
```

Or if you really want a new algorithm, at least reuse `for_each` there instead of duplicating the iteration logic:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Pred, typename Op> 
  void
  for_each_if(Iter first, Iter last, Pred p, Op op) {
    std::for_each(first, last, [&](auto& x) { if (p(x)) op(x); });
  }
```

Comment: Much better and clearer for using the standard library.

Comment: Because `std::for-each(first, last, [&](auto& x) {if (p(x)) op(x); });` is totally simpler than `for (Iter x = first; x != last; x++) if (p(x)) op(x);}`?

Comment: @immibis reusing the standard library has other benefits, such as iterator validity checking, or (in C++17) being much easier to parallelize, simply by adding one more argument:  `std::for_each(std::execution::par, first, last, ...);` How easy is it to add those things to a handwritten loop?

Comment: #pragma omp parallel for

Comment: @mark sorry, some random quirk of your source code or build chain made that annoyingly fragile parallel non-standard compiler extension generate zero performance boost with no diagnostic.

Comment: Still better supported on most compilers than standard C++03 is on Microsoft's last time I used it :)

Answer (score 21):

The idea of avoiding

```
for(...)
    if(...)
```

constructs as an antipattern is too broad.

It is completely fine to process multiple items that match a certain expression from inside a loop, and the code cannot get much clearer than that. If the processing grows too large to fit on screen, that is a good reason to use a subroutine, but still the conditional is best placed inside the loop, i.e.

```
for(...)
    if(...)
        do_process(...);
```

is vastly preferable to

```
for(...)
    maybe_process(...);
```

It becomes an antipattern when only one element will match, because then it would be clearer to first search for the element, and perform the processing outside of the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    if(i == 5)
```

is an extreme and obvious example of this. More subtle, and thus more common, is a factory pattern like

```
for(creator &c : creators)
    if(c.name == requested_name)
    {
        unique_ptr<object> obj = c.create_object();
        obj.owner = this;
        return std::move(obj);
    }
```

This is hard to read, because it isn't obvious that the body code will be executed once only. In this case, it would be better to separate the lookup:

```
creator &lookup(string const &requested_name)
{
    for(creator &c : creators)
        if(c.name == requested_name)
            return c;
}

creator &c = lookup(requested_name);
unique_ptr obj = c.create_object();
```

There is still an `if` within a `for`, but from the context it becomes clear what it does, there is no need to change this code unless the lookup changes (e.g. to a `map`), and it is immediately clear that `create_object()` is called only once, because it is not inside a loop.

Comment: I like this, as a thoughtful and balanced overview, even if it in a sense refuses to answer the question posed. I find that the `for( range ){ if( condition ){ action } }`-style makes it easy to read things one chunk at a time and only uses knowledge of the basic language constructs.

Comment: @PJTraill, the way the question was phrased reminded me of [Raymond Chen's rant against the for-if antipattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793), which has been cargo-culted and somehow became an absolute. I totally agree that `for(...) if(...) { ... }` is often the best choice (that's why I qualified the recommendation to split the action into a subroutine).

Comment: Thanks for the link, which clarified things for me: the name “**for-if**” is misleading, and should be something like “**for-all-if-one**” or “**lookup-avoidance**”. It reminds me of the way [Abstraction inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_inversion) was described by [Wikipedia in 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Abstraction_inversion&oldid=25945817) as when one “_creates simple constructs on top of complex_ (ones)” — until I rewrote it! Actually I wouldn’t even rush to fix the lookup-process-exit form of `for(…)if(…)…` if it was the only place lookup occurred.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a quick relatively minimal `filter` function.

It takes a predicate.  It returns a function object that takes an iterable.

It returns an iterable that can be used in a `for(:)` loop.

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It b, It e ) { return {std::move(b), std::move(e)}; }

template<class It, class F>
struct filter_helper:range_t<It> {
  F f;
  void advance() {
    while(true) {
      (range_t<It>&)*this = range( std::next(this->begin()), this->end() );
      if (this->empty())
        return;
      if (f(*this->begin()))
        return;
    }
  }
  filter_helper(range_t<It> r, F fin):
    range_t<It>(r), f(std::move(fin))
  {
      while(true)
      {
          if (this->empty()) return;
          if (f(*this->begin())) return;
          (range_t<It>&)*this = range( std::next(this->begin()), this->end() );
      }
  }
};

template<class It, class F>
struct filter_psuedo_iterator {
  using iterator_category=std::input_iterator_tag;
  filter_helper<It, F>* helper = nullptr;
  bool m_is_end = true;
  bool is_end() const {
    return m_is_end || !helper || helper->empty();
  }

  void operator++() {
    helper->advance();
  }
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference
  operator*() const {
    return *(helper->begin());
  }
  It base() const {
      if (!helper) return {};
      if (is_end()) return helper->end();
      return helper->begin();
  }
  friend bool operator==(filter_psuedo_iterator const& lhs, filter_psuedo_iterator const& rhs) {
    if (lhs.is_end() && rhs.is_end()) return true;
    if (lhs.is_end() || rhs.is_end()) return false;
    return lhs.helper->begin() == rhs.helper->begin();
  }
  friend bool operator!=(filter_psuedo_iterator const& lhs, filter_psuedo_iterator const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
};
template<class It, class F>
struct filter_range:
  private filter_helper<It, F>,
  range_t<filter_psuedo_iterator<It, F>>
{
  using helper=filter_helper<It, F>;
  using range=range_t<filter_psuedo_iterator<It, F>>;

  using range::begin; using range::end; using range::empty;

  filter_range( range_t<It> r, F f ):
    helper{{r}, std::forward<F>(f)},
    range{ {this, false}, {this, true} }
  {}
};

template<class F>
auto filter( F&& f ) {
    return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& r)
    {
        using std::begin; using std::end;
        using iterator = decltype(begin(r));
        return filter_range<iterator, std::decay_t<decltype(f)>>{
            range(begin(r), end(r)), f
        };
    };
};
```

I took short cuts.  A real library should make real iterators, not the `for(:)`-qualifying pseudo-fascades I did.

At point of use, it looks like this:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> test = {1,2,3,4,5};
  for( auto i: filter([](auto x){return x%2;})( test ) )
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

which is pretty nice, and prints

```
1
3
5
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31d7911a3cb214ed).

There is a proposed addition to C++ called Rangesv3 which does this kind of thing and more.  `boost` also has filter ranges/iterators available.  boost also has helpers that make writing the above much shorter.

Answer (score 15):

One style that gets used enough to mention, but hasn't been mentioned yet, is:

```
for(int i=0; i<myCollection.size(); i++) {
  if (myCollection[i] != SOMETHING)
    continue;

  DoStuff();
}
```

Advantages:

- Doesn't change the indentation level of `DoStuff();` when condition complexity increases. Logically, `DoStuff();` should be at the top-level of the `for` loop, and it is.
- Immediately makes it clear that the loop iterates over the `SOMETHING`s of the collection, without requiring the reader to verify that there is nothing after the closing `}` of the `if` block.
- Doesn't require any libraries or helper macros or functions.

Disadvantages:

- `continue`, like other flow control statements, gets misused in ways that lead to hard-to-follow code so much that some people are opposed to *any* use of them: there is a valid style of coding that some follow that avoids `continue`, that avoids `break` other than in a `switch`, that avoids `return` other than at the end of a function.

Comment: I would argue that in a `for` loop that runs to many lines, a two-line "if not, continue" is much clearer, logical, and readable. Immediately saying, "skip this if" after the `for` statement reads well and, as you said, does not indent the remaining functional aspects of the loop. If the `continue` is further down, however, some clarity is sacrificed (i.e. if some operation will always be performed before the `if` statement).

Answer (score 11):

```
for(auto const &x: myCollection) if(x == something) doStuff();
```

Looks pretty much like a C++-specific `for` comprehension to me. To you?

Comment: I don't think auto keyword was present before c++11 so I would not say it is very classical c++. If I may ask a question here in the comment, would "auto const" tell the compiler that it can rearrange all elements as it wants? Maybe it will be easier for the compiler to plan to avoid branching if that is the case.

Comment: @mathreadler The sooner people stop worrying about "classical c++", the better. C++11 was a macroevolutionary event for the language & is 5 years old: it should be the _minimum_ we strive for. Anyway, the OP tagged that and C++14 (even better!). No, `auto const` has no bearing whatsoever on iteration order. If you look up ranged-based `for`, you'll see that it basically does a standard loop from `begin()` to `end()` with implicit dereferencing. There's no way it could break the ordering guarantees (if any) of the container being iterated over; it would've been laughed off the face of the Earth

Comment: @mathreadler, actually it was, it just had quite a different meaning. What was not present is range-for... and any other distinct C++11 feature. What I meant here was that range-fors, `std::future`s, `std::function`s, even those anonymous closures are very well C++ish in the syntax; every language has its own parlance and when incorporatin new features it tries to make them mimic the old well-known syntax.

Comment: @underscore_d, a compiler is allowed to perform any transformations provided the as-if rule is obeyed, isn't it?

Comment: @bipll Well, yes, but a container with defined order must be iterated _as-if_ it's preserved, which in most cases means it'll just be iterated in that order. You'll be doing something with matches, and the compiler must assume you chose a container with well-defined order (or lack of) because you want that "something" to occur in said order. Anyway, my answer was in response to the idea that range-`for` changes behaviour compared to OP's indexed loop, which is highly unlikely: if any compiler made this byzantine transformation for range-`for`, it'd be equally free to do so for an indexed loop.

Comment: @bipll If anyone can show an example of both an optimising rationale and an extant compiler that transforms a loop over an ordered container using the _as-if_ rule to evaluate elements in a different order but despatch side-effects in the correct defined order, then that'll make my month.

Comment: @underscore_d, if one just sits at a river bank for long enough staring at the water...

Comment: What do you mean by “a C++-specific `for` comprehension”, in particular “**comprehension**”?

Comment: Hmmm, and what can possibly be meant by that?

Answer (score 7):

If DoStuff() would be dependent on i somehow in the future then I'd propose this guaranteed branch-free bit-masking variant.

```
unsigned int times = 0;
const int kSize = sizeof(unsigned int)*8;
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.size()/kSize; i++){
  unsigned int mask = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j<kSize; j++){
    mask |= (myCollection[i*kSize+j]==SOMETHING) << j;
  }
  times+=popcount(mask);
}

for(int i=0;i<times;i++)
   DoStuff();
```

Where popcount is any function doing a population count ( count number of bits = 1 ). There will be some freedom to put more advanced constraints with i and their neighbors. If that is not needed we can strip the inner loop and remake the outer loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++)
  times += (myCollection[i]==SOMETHING);
```

followed by a

```
for(int i=0;i<times;i++)
   DoStuff();
```

---

Sorry for necroing this thread, but I realized just now that my method does not explain how to store information about which "i" to use and which to skip. This can be solved with an array of pointers to objects with operator() and a "dummy object" which overloads operator() to do nothing. We insert the pointer to the dummy object in all the places where the logical condition evaluates to 0 and the pointer to the actual object wherever it evaluates to 1. If we are not dependent on some silly MISRA compliancy this can be achieved easily and neatly with arithmetics as a binary linear combination on pointers.

Another solution without dummy objects or null pointers (also avoiding possibly silly MISRA trouble) is to simply use the logical condition as a count-up variable to an index pointing into an array and just put the pointers there. This way the ones which fail the logical test will be overwritten by the ones which succeed but not the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you don't care reordering the collection, std::partition is cheap.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

void DoStuff(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 5, 0, 9, 5, 5};
    const int SOMETHING = 5;

    std::for_each(v.begin(),
                  std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(),
                                 std::bind(std::equal_to<int> {}, _1, SOMETHING)), // some condition
                  DoStuff); // action
}
```

Comment: But `std::partition` reorders the container.

Answer (score 5):

I am in awe of the complexity of the above solutions. I was going to suggest a simple `#define foreach(a,b,c,d) for(a; b; c)if(d)` but it has a few obvious deficits, for example, you have to remember to use commas instead of semicolons in your loop, and you can't use the comma operator in `a` or `c`.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

#define foreach(a,b,c,d) for(a; b; c)if(d)

int main(){
  list<int> a;

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    a.push_back(i);

  for(auto i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); i++)
    if((*i)&1)
      cout << *i << ' ';
  cout << endl;

  foreach(auto i=a.begin(), i!=a.end(), i++, (*i)&1)
    cout << *i << ' ';
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The complexity of some answers is only high because they first show a reusable generic method (which you would do only once) and then use it. Not effective if you have _one_ loop with an if condition in your whole application but very effective if it happens a thousand times.

Comment: Like most suggestions, this make it harder, not easier, to identify the range and the selection condition. And the use of a macro increases uncertainty about when (and how often) expressions are evaluated, even if there are no surprises here.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution in case the i:s are important. This one builds a list that fills in the indexes of which to call doStuff() for. Once again the main point is to avoid the branching and trade it for pipelineable arithmetic costs.

```
int buffer[someSafeSize];
int cnt = 0; // counter to keep track where we are in list.
for( int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++ ){
   int lDecision = (container[i] == SOMETHING);
   buffer[cnt] = lDecision*i + (1-lDecision)*buffer[cnt];
   cnt += lDecision;
}

for( int i=0; i<cnt; i++ )
   doStuff(buffer[i]); // now we could pass the index or a pointer as an argument.
```

The "magical" line is the buffer loading line that arithmetically calculates wether to keep the value and stay in position or to count up position and add value. So we trade away a potential branch for some logics and arithmetics and maybe some cache hits. A typical scenario when this would be useful is if doStuff() does a small amount of pipelineable calculations and any branch in between calls could interrupt those pipelines.

Then just loop over the buffer and run doStuff() until we reach cnt. This time we will have the current i stored in the buffer so we can use it in the call to doStuff() if we would need to.

Answer (score 1):

One can describe your code pattern as applying some function to a subset of a range, or in other words: applying it to the result of applying a filter to the whole range.

This is achievable in the most straightforward manner with Eric Neibler's [ranges-v3 library](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/); although it's a bit of an eyesore, because you want to work with indices:

```
using namespace ranges;
auto mycollection_has_something = 
    [&](std::size_t i) { return myCollection[i] == SOMETHING };
auto filtered_view = 
    views::iota(std::size_t{0}, myCollection.size()) | 
    views::filter(mycollection_has_something);
for (auto i : filtered_view) { DoStuff(); }
```

But if you're willing to forego indices, you'd get:

```
auto is_something = [&SOMETHING](const decltype(SOMETHING)& x) { return x == SOMETHING };
auto filtered_collection = myCollection | views::filter(is_something);
for (const auto& x : filtered_collection) { DoStuff(); }
```

which is nicer IMHO.

PS - The ranges library is mostly going into the C++ standard in C++20.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just mention Mike Acton, he would definitely say:

If you have to do that, you have a problem with your data. Sort your data!