# Ranged-based for with range_expression returning non-null items from std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Consider the following example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    std::vector<Item*> items = { nullptr, new Item(), new Item(), nullptr };

    // function to return all non-nullptr items as an iterator
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;

    for (Item* i : foo.functionToReturnIteratorOverAllNullItems)
        // do something
}
```

Is it possible to create a function inside the class to return the items in a std::vector also residing in the class, but skipping nullptr items? Or any other items for that matter. I am thinking some lambda function usage would make this work but I am not sure how.

Note I want it to be efficient without re-creating any other new vector and return that. Should preferably work in C++11.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. A vector is stored contiguously in memory. So if you want to return a vector of only items from a source vector off the top of my head your only options are to: a) Make a vector containing copies of the items you want. b) Make a vector containing pointers/refs to the items you want from the original vector. or c) sort the vector so the desired items are stored contiguously and return a begin and end iterator to the section containing those items.

Comment: Do the null pointers need to remain in the items list?

Comment: This is what ranges https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html created for IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`boost::adaptors::filtered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) (or [`ranges::view::filter`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/)):

```
// pipe version
for (Item* i : foo.items | filtered([](Item* i){return i;})) {
    // ...
}

// function version
for (Item* i : filter(foo.items, [](Item* i){return i;})) {
    // ...
}
```

This is one of the easier range adaptors to write yourself if you want a challenge. You just need an iterator type that does something slightly more complicated than forward along `++` for `operator++()`.

---

But it's probably easier to just use an `if` statement, no?

```
for (Item* i : foo.items) {
    // either positive
    if (i) {
       // ...
    }

    // or negative
    if (!i) continue;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: "Easier" only in that `boost::adaptors::filtered` requires a library you might not be using.

Comment: @NicolBolas Which for some people is an insurmountable hurdle.

Comment: C++2x coroutines make this trivial as well.

Comment: @Yakk It will eventually be?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach using higher-order functions and lambdas that abstracts the filtering logic. It does not require any additional dependency.

```
template <typename TContainer, typename TF>
auto for_nonnull_items(TContainer&& container, TF f)
{
    for(auto&& i : container)
    { 
        if(i == nullptr) continue;
        f(i);
    }

    return f;
}

std::vector<int*> example{/*...*/};
for_nonnull_items(example, [](auto ptr)
   {
       // do something with `ptr`
   });
```

---

By calling `for_nonnull_items(this->items, /*...*/)` inside `foo` you can achieve a nicer interface:

```
foo.for_nonnull_items([](auto ptr)
   {
       // do something with `ptr`
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Deriving from `std::iterator` makes custom iterators fairly trivial. In this case I have implemented a forward_only iterator. Add more features as you see fit.

```
#include <iterator>

template<class Iter>
struct non_null_forward_iterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, typename Iter::value_type>
{
    using value_type = typename Iter::value_type;

    non_null_forward_iterator(Iter i, Iter last) : iter_(i), last_(last)
    {
        seek();
    }

    value_type operator*() const {
        return *iter_;
    }

    non_null_forward_iterator& operator++() {
        ++iter_;
        seek();
        return *this;
    }

    void seek()
    {
        while (iter_ != last_) {
            if (*iter_)
                break;
            ++iter_;
        }
    }


    bool operator==(const non_null_forward_iterator& r) const {
        return iter_ != r.iter_;
    }

    bool operator!=(const non_null_forward_iterator& r) const {
        return iter_ != r.iter_;
    }

    Iter iter_;
    Iter last_;
};

template<class Container>
auto non_null_range(const Container& cont)
{
    using underlying_iter_type = typename Container::const_iterator;
    using iter_type = non_null_forward_iterator<underlying_iter_type>;

    struct X {

        iter_type begin() const { return begin_; }
        iter_type end() const { return end_; }

        iter_type begin_;
        iter_type end_;
    };

    return X {
        iter_type(cont.begin(), cont.end()),
        iter_type(cont.end(), cont.end())
    };
}

struct Item {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Item& item)
{
    return std::cout << "an item";
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<Item*> items = { nullptr, new Item(), new Item(), nullptr };

    for (auto p : non_null_range(items))
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
an item
an item
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38402087/1774667) to another SO question provides a solution that works here.  The accepted answer to the question does not.

This implements a generic filter helper in C++14.

```
for( auto ptr: filter([](auto&& x){return x!=nullptr;})( test ) )
```

will loop over the elements of `test` such that `x!=nullptr`.

Doing this in C++11 mostly consists of filling in the return types.  The exception is the final `filter` function, which returns a lambda, which is impossible in C++11, and the use of `auto&&` in the lambda above.

Many C++11 compilers support `auto` parameters to lambdas.  Those that do not, you can fold the returned lambda of `filter` and its argument into the `filter` function itself, and then write out the tedious return value.

---

C++2x TS has coroutines which make this trivial.  [The code will look roughly like](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0057r5.pdf):

```
std::generator<Item*> non_null_items() {
  for( Item* i : items )
    if ( i ) co_return i;
}
```

as a method within your class.

This mirrors similar C# and python syntax.